# How to create a user model with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, architecture, resources, models

I'd like to create a model to handle everything related to users, starting with a findOne() function.

app.js:

```
var u = new User(client);
u.findOne(function(error, user) {
  console.log(error, user);
});
```

models/User.js:

```
var User = function (client) {
  this.client = client
};
User.prototype.findOne = function (id, callback) {
  client.connect();
  client.get('testkey', function(error, result) {
    var test = "hello@world.com";
    callback(null, test);
    client.close();
  });
};
module.exports = User;
```

node.js complains findOne() would be undefined.

What's the correct way of creating such models and providing them with objects, like database pools etc.?

Comment: _client is not defined_, because ... well it's not defined inside the 'findOne' method. You should use `this.client.connect()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contains various errors:

- You do not use `new` when creating the instance
- You mixed a function with the object literal syntax:

  ```
  var User = function (client) {
    client: client
  };
  ```

  You want `this.client = client;` instead. Right now the function body does nothing as it just defines a label called `client` does nothing with the variable `client`.

I would suggest you to search for an existing ORM for node.js instead of trying to write one on your own.

Comment: I agree. I was planning to use flatiron/resourceful, but I need another engine for that, which takes time to develop.

Comment: I changed the source, it says client is not defined. This is something I tried a few times already and failed.